# dask read parquet file from spark

Tags: apache-spark, dask, parquet, dask-distributed

For a parquet file written from spark (without any partitioning) its directoy looks like:

```
%ls foo.parquet
part-00017-c17ab661-2564-428e-8233-e7a9951fb012-c000.gz.parquet
part-00018-c17ab661-2564-428e-8233-e7a9951fb012-c000.gz.parquet
part-00019-c17ab661-2564-428e-8233-e7a9951fb012-c000.gz.parquet
_SUCCESS
```

When trying to read via pandas:

```
pd.read_parquet('foo.parquet')
```

everything works fine as expected.

However, when using dask it fails:

```
dd.read_parquet('foo.parquet')
 [Errno 17] File exists: 'foo.parquet/_SUCCESS'
```

What do I need to change so that dask is able to read the data successfully?

Comment: I believe it would have worked with fastparquet too with the longer `dd.read_parquet('foo.parquet/*parquet')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that pandas is using `pyarrow`. When switching to this backend for dask:

```
 dd.read_parquet('foo.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
```

it works just like expected

Comment: However, the time required to read the parquet file even though the directory only contains about 20 files is really slow. Spark's df.show is instant. Why is dask df.head() so slow?